# CSS ribbon menu causing gap between content and header

Tags: css

I am not sure how to remove the large gap between my header and the beginning of the slideshow. [pivotalpixels.com/colusa_fair/](http://pivotalpixels.com/colusa_fair/)  I believe that the problem is something to do with the ribbon navigation but after trying tons of different things I do not know how to move the content up without the recent news moving up to right underneath the navigation bar, which needs to be under the slideshow as it currently is.

css is below

Thanks I appreciate any help!

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {  
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;  
    background-color:#c4c0be; 
    background-image:url(../images/bluewoodbkgd.jpg);
    margin:0px; padding:0px;  
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#7f7d78;  
    font-size:13px;  
    line-height:19px;  
    }  
h1{}
h2 {  
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;  
    font-size:36px;  
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;  
    color:#000000;  
    font-weight: bold;
}  
h3{font-size:16px;  color: #142b4e; font-weight: bold;}

small {  
    color:#595856;  
    font-weight:bold;  
    font-size:11px;  
    display:block;  
    margin-bottom:15px;  
}  
a {  
    color:#007de2;  
    text-decoration:none;  
}  
a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }  
p { margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; }  

#main {  
    min-height: 500px;  
    }  
#footer {  
     color:white;  
    }  
.container {  
     width:994px;  
     margin:0 auto;  
}  
#header {
   padding-top:10px;  
           margin: 0;
    }  
#logo h1 {  
    margin:0px;  
    display:block;  
    text-indent:-9999px;  
    } 
        /* Fix up IE6 PNG Support */  
img, #logo { behavior: url(scripts/iepngfix.htc); }  
#logo { 
position: absolute;
top:-25px;
        background-image:url(../images/logo_colusa.png);  
        background-repeat:no-repeat;  
        margin: 0 0 0 25px;
        width:240px;  
        height:147px;  
    }  
#navigation_container {
    width: 994px;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu{
    margin: 0;
    top:10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
}
ul#menu li {  
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        display: inline;
    }  
ul#menu li a { 
        text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
        color:#FFF;  
        font: 18px/27px 'ArvoRegular', Arial, sans-serif;  
        line-height: 28px;
    }  
ul#menu li a.active, ul#menu li a:hover {  
        color:#5a8c35;
        text-decoration: underline;
         margin-top: 2px;
} 
.rectangle {
   background: #142b4e;
   height: 52px;
   position: relative;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
   -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
   z-index: 500; /* the stack order: foreground */
   margin: 35px 0 0 0;
}
.l-triangle-top {
   border-color: #142b4e transparent transparent;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   top: 0px;
   left: -50px;
}

.l-triangle-bottom {
   border-color: transparent transparent #142b4e;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   top: -49px;
   left: -150px;
}


.r-triangle-top {
   border-color: #142b4e transparent transparent;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: relative;
        float: right;
        right: -45px;
        top: -50px;
}

.r-triangle-bottom {
   border-color: transparent transparent #142b4e;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: relative;
        float: right;
        top: -100px;
        right: -145px;
}

#sec_navigation_container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 0 0 255px;
}
ul#menu_sec{
    margin: 0;
    top:10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 110px;
}
ul#menu_sec li {  
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        display: inline;
    }  
ul#menu_sec li a { 
        text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
        color:#FFF;  
        font: 18px/27px 'ArvoRegular', Arial, sans-serif;  
        line-height: 28px;
    }  
ul#menu_sec li a.active, ul#menu_sec li a:hover {  
        color:#ce6536;
        text-decoration: underline;
         margin-top: 2px;
} 
.rectangle_mainsec {
   background: #ce6536;
   height: 52px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 500; /* the stack order: foreground */
   margin: 0;
}
.l-triangle-top-sec {
   border-color: #ce6536 transparent transparent;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   top: 0px;
   left: -50px;
}

.l-triangle-bottom-sec {
   border-color: transparent transparent #ce6536;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   top: -49px;
   left: -150px;
}


.r-triangle-top-sec {
   border-color: #ce6536 transparent transparent;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: relative;
        float: right;
        right: -125px;
        top: -53px;
}

.r-triangle-bottom-sec {
   border-color: transparent transparent #ce6536;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: relative;
        float: right;
        top: -100px;
        right: -225px;
}




        /*  
        Block-Styles  
    */  

.block {  
        margin-bottom:20px;  
    }  
.block_inside {   
        padding:0 20px;  
    }  

.image_block {  
        border:1px solid #557f9d;  
        background-color:#ffffff;  
        padding:5px;  
        float:left;  
}  
.image_block img {  
     border:1px solid #b5b5b5; 
    }  
#block_slideshow{
    overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}
.upcoming_events {  
        float:left;  
        width:315px; 
        height: 325px;
        margin-left:30px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #557f9d;
         background-color:#ffffff;
}  
  .upcoming_events h2, #event_items h2{
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    font: 24px/27px 'DancingScriptOTRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 20px 6px 30px;
    margin: 4px 10px 10px -31px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5a8c35;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #7c7c7c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px #295e04;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px #295e04;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px #295e04;
    border: 1px solid #295e04;
}
  .upcoming_events h2:before, #event_items h2:before
{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -2px;
    top: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:20px;
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
}
  .upcoming_events h2:after, #event_items h2:after{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    border-width: 5px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #295e04 #295e04 transparent transparent;
}   
.block_content{ padding: 10px;}
#block_recent{overflow:auto;  
    margin-bottom:20px;  }


#event_items {  
    width:560px;  
    margin-right:25px;  
    margin-left: 20px;
    float:left;  
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #557f9d;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}  
#countdown {  
    float:right;  
    width:332px; 
    height: 175px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-image: url(../images/countdown.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  
}  
#block_right {  
    float:right;  
    width:332px; 
    height: 175px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-image: url(../images/countdown.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  
}  

.mini_event_item {  
    width: 48%;
    margin: 5px 0px 10px 10px; 
    float: left;
}  
.date{color: #5a8c35; font-weight: bold;}
.mini_event_item .block_inside {   

    padding:25px 30px 15px 30px;   
}  
.mini_event_item .thumbnail { float:left; margin-right:20px; border:1px solid #979390; }  

#sponsors{margin: 10px 0px; padding: 10px; height: 95px; background-color: #142b4e;  }
.sponsor_item,footer_item{float: left; margin-right: 10px; padding: 10px; height: 70px; background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #000;}
#footer {  
     font: 18px/27px 'ArvoRegular', Arial, sans-serif; 

}  
.footer_column {  
    float:left;  
    width:300px;  
    margin-right:10px;  
}  
#footer .long {  
    width:670px;  
}  
#footer h3 {  
    color:#fff; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
} 
#footer h4{
    font-size: 16px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
#footer p{ font-size: 12px;
}
ul.industry_links{
    padding: 10px; 
    display: inline;
}
ul.industry_links li {  
   float:left; 
   list-style:none;
   text-align: center;

} 
ul.industry_links li a{
    display:block;
    width: 135px;
    height: 79px;
    margin-right: 10px; 
   padding: 10px;   
   background-color: #ffffff; 
   border: 1px solid #039;
      text-align: center;
}
.footer_column ul li, .footer_column ul {  
    list-style:none;  
    margin:0px;  
    padding:0px;  
    font-size: 12px;

}
```

Comment: ......what slideshow? There is no slideshow on the link you provided.

Comment: The issue appears to be (mostly) coming from you `#sec_navigation_container`.  If add `display:none` to it, it will move the slideshow content up much closer to the branding/logo.  I've not pinpointed the exact cause, but I suspect it's related how some elements are relatively positioned.

Comment: @Colleen If you inspect the page source, you'll see a block called `block_slideshow`, which is the content with the large image and "upcoming events" list.

Comment: Those relatively positioned elements, which are being used to create the triangles on the ends of the ribbons in the header, are one of the main contributors. They have no size and a huge border width to create the triangles. If you remove the border width on these four elements, then the content moves up much closer to the header nav. There's still some space left for which I can't find the cause, but you may want to rethink how you do the triangle effect, perhaps absolutely position those divs instead of relatively so that they're removed from content flow completely?

Comment: Missed two other triangle divs. There are six in total, and those are pushing your content down. You can see that they are the culprits if you temporarily remove the border width on them.

Comment: @ajp15243 nailed it.  You're using the "CSS Triangles" trick which has a 50px width and that's where it's coming from.

Comment: sorry yes eventually that picture will be a slideshow, @jmbertucci that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @user2287584 Just to see the effect, did you remove `border-width` on the following classes: `l-triangle-top`, `l-triangle-bottom`, `r-triangle-top`, `r-triangle-bottom`, `r-triangle-top-sec`, `r-triangle-bottom-sec`? You're going to have to tweak how you make CSS triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `r-triangle-top-sec` and `r-triangle-bottom-sec` elements that generate the "ribbon" effect are using the "CSS Triangle Trick" which requires a large border size (50px in this case).

This is causing a lot of extra height due to the invisible border rendering.

One quick fix is to `position:absolute` these elements.

First, make the container `position:relative` so the child elements will use it as a positioning reference point

```
#sec_navigation_container{
    position:relative /* Add */
    /*...*/
}
```

Add this to `r-triange-top-sec`

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: -50px;
```

Add this to `r-triange-bottom-sec`

```
position: absolute;
top: -50px;
right: -50px;
```

That should get rid of some of that spacing.  Applying this idea to the upper "ribbon" might help as well.

**UPDATE**

Turns out, the exact same code can be used for the blue ribbon as well.  Rinse/repeate the above code but for `#navigation_container`, `l-triangle-top` and `l-triangle-bottom`.

That will move your "slideshow" content flush to the navigation.

You can then add some margin to your `#header` element such as:

```
margin-bottom:2em;
```

to push that "slideshow" back down to a desired separation. (adjust the valid as desired)

*note* I just eyeballed the placement of the ribbon.  Please adjust top/right position as needed for your design

I hope that helps!

Comment: I'll update this in a sec once I have the "blue ribbon" CSS worked out. That will make the "slideshow" be completely flush with the header nav.

Comment: +1 for `position: absolute`, which will remove the triangle `div`s from the content flow, meaning they will not affect the layout of everything else, which is what caused the huge space. Hopefully that fixes all of it.

Comment: Awesome that worked perfect thanks to ajp15243 and jmbertucci!  Thanks sooo much!